# Confirm result of left join sybase query

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I need some help with sybase sql syntax. Going through some example questions after many years of being away from sql. Given the following two sybase table structures and data:

Table name: users

```
| name | salary |
| joe  | 100000 |
| nick | 10000  |
```

Table name: user_data

```
| name | percent |
| joe  | 0.67    |
```

and the following query:

```
select u.name, ud.percent from users u, user_data ud where u.name *= ud..name
```

am I right in thinking that the output will be:

```
| name | percent |
| joe  | 0.67    |
| nick | NULL    |
```

based on the reasoning that the *= means left join?

The other question I had is what does the '..' mean in the ud..name?

Thanks.

Comment: Referring to 'The other question I had', you should ask any other question in a new `Question`. Like 'What does a double dot syntax in Sybase SQL mean?'

Comment: @Aquillo Ok. I thought since both questions were about the same query I could ask here but happy to leave that one for another question.

Comment: Well, it's for the sake of readability and finding the right answers to the right questions. There's no problem in copying half your question from the `edit` window to minimize any trouble in making another question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is older JOIN syntax that has been replaced with ANSI JOIN syntax.  The query should be written:

```
select u.name, ud.percent 
from users u
left join user_data ud 
  on u.name = ud.name
```

This query will return all `users` in your table even if there is not a matching row in the `user_data` table. For those rows not in the table a `null` will be returned.

Comment: Hello again @bluefeet! An sql warrior's 24 hr real time support! ;) Thanks. Btw - what does the double dot in ud..name mean in that query?

Comment: @junkie It is a four part naming convention -- see this link -- http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic585446-338-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks. That explains why I couldn't find any decent google results. I was searching for 'two dots' in UK English instead of 'two periods'. :)